# Truncating text in div inside td (Width in unit relative)

Tags: html, css, truncate

I need to truncate the text only with css of the following example.

[Example of the problem in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m4rLo0ew/)

```
<table border="1" width="100%" cellspacing="1" cellpading="1">   
  <tr>
    <td align="center" width="50%">
      <div>test1 test1 test1 test1test1 test1test1 test1test1   test1test1 test1test1 test1test1 test1test1 test1</div>
    <td align="center" width="50%">
      <div>TEST2</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I probe truncating directly in the div but it does not work with relative measures.

[Example in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L97yo3td/)

```
<table border="1" width="100%" cellspacing="1" cellpading="1">   
  <tr>
    <td align="center" width="50%">
      <div style="    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;">test1 test1 test1 test1test1 test1test1 test1test1   test1test1 test1test1 test1test1 test1test1 test1</div>
    <td align="center" width="50%">
      <div style="    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;">TEST2</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Any ideas?. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use "text-overflow: ellipsis".

```
...
  <div id="test">test1 test1 test1 test1test1 test1test1 test1test1   test1test1 test1test1 test1test1 test1test1 test1</div>
...
```

css file :

```
#test{  
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Somewhere in your JS code :

```
$("#test").width(200);
```

This will give you : "test1 test1 test1 test1test1 test1te..."

Is this usefull ?

Comment: Hi vanessa. I need to keep the width of the cell in relative measure, I can not use an absolute measure of 200px width, to solve this problem :(.

Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Ok, and if you manage the "#test" width in jquery ? I update the code.

Comment: I can use only css

Comment: Do you have another div to get width from it ? (with css)